# Проблема с Live Sass Compiler в VSCode - бесконечное Watching

Tags: visual-studio-code

Установил расширение Sass (на дополнение: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented) для распознавания и Live Sass Compiler (популярное расширение: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass).
Изменил путь и решил попробовать скомпилировать, но началась бесконечное ожидания компиляции (ждал вплоть до часа - никакого результата) [image: Waiting...]
После этой ошибки решил ещё раз попробовать полазить внутри json, нашел вот такой "рабочий" код на просторах stack:

```
{
   "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
    {
       "extensionName": ".css",
       "format": "expanded",
       "savePath": "/SecondStudyProject/css/"
    }
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
     "**/node_modules/**",
     ".vscode/**",
     ".git/**"
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
      "> 1%",
      "last 10 versions"
 ],
 "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
 }
```

Пробовал также все сохранить, убрать дополнение Sass, перевести в Scss и так сохранить, удалить расширения и скачать только LSC, но безрезультатно - ожидания около часа ни к чему не привели.. В чем ошибка и почему проблема - не в курсе. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь

Comment: Может быть проблема в .sass файле . Комментарии или какие символы мешают. Надо смотреть в консоле

Comment: Вы решили свою проблему? У меня такая же(